# ClassNotFound error for HibernateJPAVendorAdapter class

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-entitymanager

I am creating unit testcases for JPAs using DBUnit and H2. I get following error when I try to run the tests. My JPA runs perfectly fine when I run the project with actual database. I get the error while running unit tests.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:com.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter
```

Here is snippet from my POM file

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-mock</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <version>2.0.8</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.5</version>
</dependency> 
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.2</version>
</dependency>
 <dependency>
  <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
  <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
  <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
    <version>20030825.183949</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.0.ga</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.2.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javassist</groupId>
    <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
    <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
    <version>11.2.0</version>
</dependency>
<!-- Tibco -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.tibco</groupId>
    <artifactId>mytibjms</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.easymock</groupId>
    <artifactId>easymock</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <version>3.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.8.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
    <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.11</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.springtestdbunit</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-test-dbunit</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.dbunit</groupId>
    <artifactId>dbunit</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.9</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.6</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.16</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.jolbox</groupId>
  <artifactId>bonecp-provider</artifactId>
  <version>0.8.0-alpha1</version>
</dependency>
```

Please let me know where is the problem.

Many Thanks
Suman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be a dependency conflicts for spring-orm, which version of spring framework are you using? There might be two version of spring-orm in your project dependencies, exlude one from you pom.

it is likely caused by:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-mock</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <version>2.0.8</version>
</dependency>
```

spring-mock 2.0.8 may depends on an old version of spring-orm

use **mvn dependency:tree** to generate the dependency tree, and make sure there is only one spring-orm

edit...

it must be a typo, just update the full path of the class from:

```
com.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter
```

to:

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I generated dependency tree and it shows only one spring-orm jar. I use spring version 3.2.3 Release. Kindly suggest.

Comment: can you try **mvn -X test** and post the stack trace of the errors?

Comment: ah...I see, the full path must be **org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter** instead of **com.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter**

Answer (score 0):

You had spring-orm in your maven dependencies which should contain HibernateJpaVendorAdapter so I think the problem is with the way you're running the unit test.

Try running the unit test using maven (eg: `mvn test`). It seems whatever mechanism you used to run you unit test isn't including that jar into the classpath.

Comment: I ran mvn test it also gives the same error. Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter